# Different calculation results of an area between OpenLayers and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openlayers

In OpenLayers I draw a 5 meter * 5 meter rectangle.

If I calculate the area of the geometry in OpenLayers I get 25 m^2. But in PostGIS I'm getting 25.04. I need to get the same result.

OpenLayers:

```
const factor = getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, coordinate);
const squareMeter = polygon.getArea() * Math.pow(factor, 2);
```

PostGIS:

```
select ST_Area(ST_Transform(postgis_area_geometry, 4326)::geography) from geometry_table where id=1;
```

Comment: A rectangle projected onto a sphere will necessarily cover more area than the product of its side length - just as all its angles must be larger than 90 degrees each. You can try 'ST_Area' on the EPSG:3857 geometries, rather than requesting a (correct) spheroidal calculation.

Comment: What do you get with `select ST_Area(postgis_area_geometry) from geometry_table where id=1;`?

Comment: What do you get with `getArea(polygon)`? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_sphere.html#.getArea

Comment: The only thing I can say for certain is that your 25 sq. m. in 3857 certainly isn't  25 sq. m. in real world units. Web Webcator isn't capable of generating accurate area.

Comment: @Mike: I get 24.94.

Comment: @user30184: I get 66.99 if I just use ST_Area.

Comment: @Vince I calculate 5 meter length to map units first, so it should be real 5 meter: const factor = getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, coordinate); const lengthInMapUnits = 5 / factor;

Comment: No, Web Mercator *cannot* result in correct distance measurement. Distance gets progressively worse away from the Equator, with the poles infinitely distant. 3857 also uses a spherical model, not the spheroidal model used by `geography`.